# Web Scraper freezes on digital ocean vps

Tags: python, web-scraping, redis, queue, vps

I have this scraper build with asyncio and httpx and it triggers on POST request where a user uploads the list of keywords as a csv file. Everything working fine locally but it hangs up when I try to do 50+ keywords on digital ocean server.

my api code fragment:

```
import fastapi as _fastapi
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, FileResponse, Response, RedirectResponse, StreamingResponse
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.templating import Jinja2Templates
import shutil
import os
import time

from rq import Queue
from rq.job import Job

from redis import Redis

from scraper import run_scraper
from utils import clean_file, csv_writer

app = _fastapi.FastAPI()

r = Redis(
    host="localhost",
    port=6379,
    db=0,
)
q = Queue(connection=r, default_timeout=-1)

templates = Jinja2Templates("templates")




@app.get("/")
def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})


@app.post("/api/v1/scraped_csv")
async def extract_ads(csv_file: _fastapi.UploadFile = _fastapi.File(...)):
    temp_file = _save_file_to_disk(csv_file, path="temp", save_as="temp")
    task = q.enqueue(run_scraper, temp_file)

    return RedirectResponse(f'/progress/{task.id}', status_code=303)
    


@app.get("/progress/{job_id}")
def progress(request: Request, job_id):
    job = Job.fetch(job_id, connection=r)
    if job.is_finished:
        csv_path = os.path.abspath(clean_file)
        return FileResponse(path=csv_path, media_type="text/csv", filename=clean_file)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("log_stream.html", {"request": request})


@app.get("/log_stream/")
def stream():
    def iterfile():
        with open("scraper.log") as log_info:
            while True:
                where = log_info.tell()
                line = log_info.readline()
                if not line:
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    log_info.seek(where)
                else:
                    yield line

   
    return StreamingResponse(iterfile(), media_type="text/plain")


def _save_file_to_disk(uploaded_file, path=".", save_as="default"):
    extension = os.path.splitext(uploaded_file.filename)[-1]
    temp_file = os.path.join(path, save_as + extension)
    with open(temp_file, "wb") as buffer:
        shutil.copyfileobj(uploaded_file.file, buffer)
    return temp_file
```

I am using redis queue and make scraping in the background because of request timeout issue.

my scraper code fragment:

```
import httpx
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from decouple import config
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os
import logging

from utils import csv_reader, csv_writer

SCRAPERAPI_KEY = config("API_KEY")
NUM_RETRIES = 3

logging.basicConfig(filename="scraper.log",
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    filemode='w')

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


base_url = "https://www.google.com/search?"

headers = {
    "authority": "www.google.com",
    "sec-ch-dpr": "1",
    "sec-ch-viewport-width": "1366",
    "sec-ch-ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Yandex";v="22"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-full-version": '"22.3.3.886"',
    "sec-ch-ua-arch": '"x86"',
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Linux"',
    "sec-ch-ua-platform-version": '"5.4.0"',
    "sec-ch-ua-model": '""',
    "sec-ch-ua-bitness": '"64"',
    "sec-ch-ua-full-version-list": '" Not A;Brand";v="99.0.0.0", "Chromium";v="98.0.4758.886", "Yandex";v="22.3.3.886"',
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.141 Safari/537.36",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "referer": "https://www.google.com/",
    "accept-language": "en,ru;q=0.9",
}

pagination_params = {
    "q": "lift installation",
    "source": "lnms",
    "tbm": "shop",
    "ei": "aW-HYv74MrCOseMP_8OumAY",
    "start": "",
    "sa": "X",
    "ved": "0ahUKEwikobSm8e33AhUjUGwGHQVfDr84PBDy0wMIpw0",
    "biw": "480",
    "bih": "665",
    "dpr": "1",
}

initial_params = {
    "q": "",
    "source": "lnms",
    "tbm": "shop",
    "sa": "X",
    "ved": "0ahUKEwikobSm8e33AhUjUGwGHQVfDr84PBDy0wMIpw0",
    "biw": "480",
    "bih": "665",
    "dpr": "1",
}

results = []


def get_scraperapi_url(url):
    payload = {
        "api_key": SCRAPERAPI_KEY,
        "url": url,
        "country_code": "au",
        "keep_headers": "true",
    }
    proxy_url = "http://api.scraperapi.com/?" + urlencode(payload)
    return proxy_url


async def log_request(request):
    logger.debug(f"Request: {request.method} {request.url}")


async def log_response(response):
    request = response.request
    logger.debug(f"Response: {request.method} {request.url} - Status: {response.status_code}")


async def fetch_pages(keyword, page_no):
    initial_params["q"] = keyword
    if not page_no:
        params = initial_params
        url = base_url + urlencode(params)
    else:
        params = pagination_params

        params["start"] = str(page_no * 10)

        params["q"] = keyword
        url = base_url + urlencode(params)

    async with httpx.AsyncClient(
        event_hooks={"request": [log_request], "response": [log_response]}
    ) as client:
        response = await client.get(
            get_scraperapi_url(url), headers=headers, timeout=None
        )

        return response


async def parse_page(html):

    ad_urls = []
    content = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    for ad in content.find_all("a", {"class": "sh-np__click-target"}):
        try:
            async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
                r = await client.get(
                    "https://www.google.com" + ad["href"], headers=headers, timeout=None
                )
                url = str(r.url)
                ad_urls.append(urlparse(url).netloc)
                logger.debug(urlparse(url).netloc)
        except:
            pass

    for idx in range(len(ad_urls)):

        results.append({"Ad_Url": ad_urls[idx]})

    return results


async def run_scraper(file_path):
    tasks = []
    kw = await csv_reader(file_path)
    for k in kw:
        for page in range(0, 4):
            for _ in range(NUM_RETRIES):
                try:
                    response = await fetch_pages(k, page)
                    if response.status_code in [200, 404]:
                        break
                except httpx.ConnectError:
                    response = ""
            if response.status_code == 200:
                tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(parse_page(response.content)))

    ad_data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    logger.info('Done!')
    await csv_writer(ad_data[0])
    logger.info('csv created.. Please refresh the page to download the csv.')
    

    return ad_data[0]
```

gunicorn.py

```
import multiprocessing
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

name = "gunicorn config for FastAPI - TutLinks.com"
accesslog = "/root/fastapi_google_ads_scraper/google_ad_scraper/gunicorn-access.log"
errorlog = "/root/fastapi_google_ads_scraper/google_ad_scraper/gunicorn-error.log"

bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"

worker_class = "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count () * 2 + 1
worker_connections = 1024
backlog = 2048
max_requests = 5120
timeout = 0
keepalive = 2

debug = os.environ.get("debug", "false") == "true"
reload = debug
preload_app = False
daemon = False
```

Digital Ocean VPS: 8gb ram, 4 AMD vcpus, 25gb disk, Ubuntu 20.04

Scraper just hangs up without any errors and I have declared the `default_timeout=-1` in redis queue because some of the requests do take time more than usual. I have tried to run the scraper independently under vps to see whether it is scraper issue or api but the scraper itself hang up for hours at the last keyword. Any ideas on how to solve this issue? I have been hitting my head against the wall for weeks now but couldn't figure out. Thank you

Comment: did you check if you can access these urls directly from VPS - using ie `curl` or `ping`. Maybe `Digital Ocean` is blocking access to external servers for security reason - and to stop using its servers for scraping (because some portals treat scraping as stealing data). OR maybe other urls stop access from `Digital Ocean` because they know that conection from `Digital Ocean` can means only bots and stealing data.

Comment: No it is not blocking issue because I am using proxy and every url is hit but when it comes to the end it just hangs up.

Comment: this can means destination server blocks it - it can do it when it thinks that it spamer/bots/hacker. Other portal may also doesn't like proxy server which you use.

Comment: I have changed the proxy server but the same result hangs up in the end after parsing all the data.